# Alfresco 6.2 Solr waiting for updated index in ITs

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

We are currently upgrading our Alfresco 5.x to Alfresco 6.2 but we have troubles with our integration-tests especially the ones which are creating and searching for nodes.
The integration-tests were using the NO INDEX Solr which makes the created nodes searchable immediately but now with a separate Solr instance with Alfresco 6 we have to wait until Solr indexed the new nodes.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I know Alfresco only triggers committed transactions for Solr indexing which means either

- a `@Test` has to succeed to successfully commit a transaction or
- I have to begin a new transaction with the `RetryingTransactionHelper` in which I create new nodes

Using the `RetryingTransactionHelper` works **but** afterward I have to wait until the new data has been index.

(**tl;dr**) How do I check if new nodes have been indexed in Solr to use the `org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchService` in my integration-tests?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I understand your issue, SOLR is eventually consistent by design?

Comment: You are right. I am going to try the java awaitility library maybe it works for my use case.